# R as a general purpose programming language

Tags: python, r, wiki, language-features

I liked Python before because Python has rich built-in types like sets, dicts, lists, tuples. These structures help write short scripts to process data.

On the other side, R is like Matlab, and has scalar, vector, data frame, array and list as its data types. But it lacks sets, dicts, tuples, etc. I know that list type is powerful, a lot of operations could be thought as list processing. But the idea of using R as a general purpose language is still vague.

(The following is just **an example**. Not mean that I focus on text processing/mining.)

For example, I need to do TF-IDF counting for a set of news articles (say 200,000 articles in a folder and its sub folders).

After I read the files, I need to do word-to-ID mapping and other counting tasks. These tasks involve string manipulation and need containers like set or map.

I know I can use another language to do these processing and load the data into R. But maybe (for small things) putting all preprocessing into a single R script is better.

So my question is does R have enough capability in this kind of rich data structures in the language level? Or If not, any packages provide good extension for R language?

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question, but are you aware of things like rpy2? It allows you to turn Python objects into R objeccts and use R functions on them. So you can do Python processing, then R processing in the same script, albeit with a slightly longer syntax.

Comment: @Thomas Not quite a solution. My concern is that I want to stick on R and use as less external stuff as possible. Especially when I give out my code, it would be better if the end user only needs to install R.

Comment: sets are available in the `sets` package.  Since vectors have named elements, they behave very similarly to dicts for most purposes.  (A data.frame with id and value columns also works as a dict.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that R's data pre-processing capability--i.e., everything from extracting data from its source and just before the analytics steps--has improved substantially in the past three years (the length of time i have been using R). I use python daily and have for the past seven years or so--its text-processing capabilities are superb--and still i wouldn't hesitate for a moment to use R for the type of task you mention.

A couple of provisos though. First, i would suggest looking very closely at a couple of the *external* packages for the set of tasks in your Q--in particular, ***hash*** (python-like key-value data structure), and ***stringr*** (consists mostly of wrappers over the less user-friendly string manipulation functions in the the base library)

Both *stringr* and *hash* are available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).

```
> library(hash)
> dx = hash(k1=453, k2=67, k3=913)
> dx$k1
  [1] 453
> dx = hash(keys=letters[1:5], values=1:5)
> dx
  <hash> containing 5 key-value pair(s).
   a : 1
   b : 2
   c : 3
   d : 4
   e : 5

> dx[a]
  <hash> containing 1 key-value pair(s).
  a : 1

> library(stringr)
> astring = 'onetwothree456seveneight'
> ptn = '[0-9]{3,}'
> a = str_extract_all(astring, ptn)
> a
  [[1]]
  [2] "456"
```

It seems also that there is a large subset of R users for whom text processing and text analytics comprise a significant portion of their day-to-day work--as evidenced by CRAN's [Natural Language Processing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) (one of about 20 such informal domain-oriented Package collections). Within that Task View is the package [tm](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/), a package dedicated to functions for text mining. Included in ***tm*** are optimized functions for processing tasks such as the one mentioned in your Q.

In addition, R has an excellent selection of packages for working interactively on reasonably large datasets (e.g., > 1 GB) often without the need to set up a parallel processing infrastructure (but which can certainly exploit a cluster if it's available). The most impressive of these in my opinion are the set of packages under the rubric "[The Bigmemory Project](http://www.bigmemory.org/)" (CRAN) by Michael Kane and John Emerson at Yale; this Project subsumes bigmemory, biganalytics, synchronicity, bigtabulate, and bigalgebra. In sum, the techniques behind these Packages include: (i) allocating the data to shared memory, which enables coordination of shared access by separate concurrent processes to a single copy of the data; (ii) file-backed data structures (which i believe, but i am not certain, is synonymous with a memory-mapped file structure, and which works enabling very fast access from disk using pointers thus avoiding the RAM limit on available file size).

Still, quite a few functions and data structures in R's standard library make it easier to work interactively with data approaching ordinary RAM limits. For instance, .RData, a native binary format, is about as simple as possible to use (the commands are *save* and *load*) and it has excellent compression:

```
> library(ElemStatLearn)
> data(spam)
> format(object.size(spam), big.mark=',')
  [1] "2,344,384" # a 2.34 MB data file
> save(spam, file='test.RData')
```

This file, 'test.RData' is only **176 KB**, greater than *10-fold* compression.

Comment: +1 - great answer! I learned quite a few things there..

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing us to the `hash` and `tm` packages

Answer (score 4):

This is just not true that R lacks sets, dicts, lists and tuples; they are just implemented as some other structures. Of course performance may be a problem, but usually it is not worse than Python's, and you usually can find a package that has the solution coded as an efficient C code.

I don't know much about text mining, but [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) package may contain what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [Natural Language Processing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).

Topic Headings:

Phonetics and Speech Processing:
Lexical Databases:
Keyword Extraction and General String Manipulation:
Natural Language Processing:
String Kernels:
Text Mining: